# NoReverseMatch at / Python Django

Tags: python, django

I'm taking a Django course, and I'm having the next error:

> Reverse for 'products.views.product_detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

I'm trying to send an argument to a view from a file that is called index.html

My index.html looks like this:

```
{% for pr in product %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'products.views.product_detail' pr.pk %}">{{ pr.name }} </a>
                | {{ pr.description }}
                <img src="{{ pr.imagen.url }}" alt="">
            </li>
{% endfor%}
```

I already declared the url that is associated:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='views.product_detail')
]
```

And my views.py looks like this:

```
def product_detail(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk = pk)
    template = loader.get_template('product_detail.html')
    context = {
        'product': product
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Does someone know why is this error happening?

Thanks.

Comment: try to use `<a href="{% url 'views.product_detail' pr.pk %}">{{ pr.name }} </a>` instead. I don't think you are referencing the url name correctly in your template tag. AFAIK it should be the same as the `name` argument of your `url` pattern. And really, you should probably get rid of the `views.` part of the name, i.e., just use `name='product_detail'` in your url pattern, and `"{% url 'product_detail' pr.pk %}"` in your template.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: I'm using  Django 1.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From ["Features to be removed in 1.10"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10):

> - The ability to reverse() URLs using a dotted Python path is removed.

The `{% url %}` tag uses `reverse()`, so the same applies. As elethan mentioned in the comments, you need to use the `name` parameter provided in your URLconf instead, in this case `views.product_detail`:

```
{% for pr in product %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'views.product_detail' pr.pk %}">{{ pr.name }} </a>
                | {{ pr.description }}
                <img src="{{ pr.imagen.url }}" alt="">
            </li>
{% endfor %}
```